# Were all but one of the US presidents descended from King John of England?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, population

The [Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2183858/All-presidents-bar-directly-descended-medieval-English-king.html#ixzz23KbuiKJl) says:

> A 12-year-old girl created family tree linking 42 of 43 U.S. presidents to King John of England, who signed the Magna Carta in 1215.
>   Only the eighth president, Martin Van Buren, was not related to John.

This has been recently spreading on news web-sites and Facebook, especially by conspiracy theorists.

Is this true?

Comment: Here's the conspiracy theory aspect: The [Most Royal Candidate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_royal_candidate_theory) theory suggests the candidate with the closest ties to European royalty is always elected, thus proving that election results are organised by the Illuminati...

Comment: It's interesting that people believe this, but this is [The Daily Mail](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5eBT6OSr1TI) we are talking about!

Comment: If on average every descendant has 1.5 children who have descendants in turn, and a generation is 20 years, then John would have more than 600 million descendants by now...

Comment: @hdhondt But every inbreeding event cuts a branch ... :D

Comment: That's why I did not make it an answer. I'm sure this is the reason, but I don't know which assumptions to use. While inbreeding cuts branches, most people also had way more than 4 kids, as well as more than 1.5 producing offspring. I just picked some numbers that sounded not too far out. If someone can put some real numbers in this, it would make an answer.

Comment: This is similar to a question I asked some time ago about whether [all the presidents were descended from George Washington](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/7344/1792).

Comment: This story [dates back to at least 2010](http://www.santacruzsentinel.com/ci_14408412)

Comment: 6 degrees of Francis bacon...

Comment: A bunch of European royality had the right of the first night. They could also rape women without negative consequences for themselves, especially in wartime. Those relations won't show up in official family trees but I would suspect that all Americans of European descent are related to King John of England.

Comment: What I have difficulty believing is that the genealogy of all those presidents is known that far back. 1215 is a heck of a long time ago (especially for Americans!)

Comment: @Christian Wikipedia is somewhat sceptical of those claims being the case in Europe: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droit_du_seigneur

Comment: @Sklivvz My deleted answer may not give a yes/no answer, but it does specifically address this part of the question: "is there a statistical explanation that makes this more likely than it seems?". My answer is a clear "yes" to that.

Comment: @hdhondt that part of the question is leading and off-topic. Thus I am editing it out. Furthermore, your maths is off (but math discussions are off topic here, so I will only elaborate in the [chat]).